# How to automate DMS tasks in AWS cli in AWS Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dms

Is there any chance to automate DMS tasks in AWS DMS I am trying below command to automate?

```
aws dms start-replication-task <arn> --start-replication-task-type start-replication
```

But its not allowing and facing below error while running above command.

```
user is not authorized to perform: dms:StartReplicationTask on resource:<arn> because no identity-based policy allows the dms:StartReplicationTask action
```

Please let me know which permission are required to AWS user

Answer (score 0):

You user needs an IAM role assigned to it with appropriate permissions. The permissions required for DMS are listed on AWS website at the below link.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Security.html#CHAP_Security.IAMPermissions

Have a read through, it should solve your problem.
regards,
Naveed.